# Swagger page is not display as startup page in IIS for .net core 3.1 Web API

Tags: iis, swagger-ui, .net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have published web API application(.Net Core 3.1) on IIS under Default Web Site.
I have follow the all necessary steps to host .net core application on IIS.
Using postman tool I have checked that all API are working correctly.

As I want to show Swagger UI page as startup page after browsing the API from IIS.
From IIS whenever I have clicked on [browse:XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 (https) ] link it shows **This XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX page can’t be found**

browser URL :  https://https/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/API

Note: If I have added "/" at end of above url then it automatically redirect to swagger's Index.html page.

My existing source code for swagger

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0.0", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "TestAPI",
            Version = "v1.0.0",
            Description = "Test API"
        });

        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
   {
      c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1.0.0/swagger.json", "TestAPI V1.0.0");
      c.RoutePrefix = "";
   });
}
```

In IIS I have added application by the name (API).
I want to show swagger Index.html page as default page after accessing from IIS.

I don not understand that anything is missing at code level or need to do any setting on IIS to display default swagger page.

**Additional Information:**

Swagger Package:  Swashbuckle.AspNeteCore(5.3.1)

OS: Windoes 10

IIS : 10.0.19041.1

Note: Same API I have published as NewWebSite(Not under Default Web Site) on IIS then it works as par expectation.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same situation, Could you please post your solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find solution for the same when running on IIS. My requirement was to use above API URL directly in my Web UI project so I have not checked in detail regarding this issue.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, Swagger was working but it was just not showing as startup page. Adding **"launchUrl": "swagger"** under profiles in **launchsettings.json** worked for me.

```
{ 
  "iisSettings": {
    ...
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "swagger",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: In my case, the server was not generating any layout for swagger even though it navigated me to the swagger url. I needed to add a `/` at the end of swagger to make it work: `"launchUrl: "swagger/"`

Answer (score 0):

this settings works for me.

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My Api v1");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically, all you have done is enough to configure the `Swagger UI` extension.
After we set up the below code segments for the `Swagger JSON` file, the base address of the website will display the `Swagger` index page.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

At the same time, the `Swagger.json` file can be generated properly when we configured the XML comments path.

```
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

Official tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
There might be something wrong with the IIS configuration. On my side, both the default web site and a new website work properly. I doubt if there are some URL rules in your default website. Please check if the URL rules exist under the URL Rewrite extension of the default web site.
Besides, please clear the local browser cache, or verify it in a private window of the browser, after we removed some URL rules.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.